# Bounded sequence with repelling terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was wondering: Is it possible to construct a bounded sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers satisfying $|a_n-a_{n+k}| > 1/k \, \forall k \geq 1$? I've tried to come up with such a sequence, to no avail.  But I have no idea how to disprove this, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Perhaps the simplest example is: $$a_n\equiv n\;(\!\!\!\!\!\!\mod\! \alpha)\quad\text{with}\quad0\leqslant a_n<\alpha\text{ for }n\in \Bbb N,$$where $\alpha^2-3\alpha+1=0$ with $\alpha>2$. A proof of this can be found in my paper "How slowly can a bounded sequence cluster?", published in *Functiones et Approximatio* **46**(2), pp. 195--204 (2012). Another, rational, sequence with the same property is discussed in this paper and further in "A maximally separated sequence", *ibid* **48**(1), pp. 117--22 (2013).

**Edit:** I realize that you had strict inequality ($>1$) in your question; you can get this from my sequence simply by scaling it up by any factor exceeding $1$.